# What is this rattling noise when car put in reverse or drive gear? (2014 Honda CR-V)

Tags: honda, noise, transmission, rattle

I recently bought a used 2014 Honda CR-V. I noticed in my garage today, that there is a strange rattling noise right when I put the car in reverse or drive gear. It is much more pronounced when the car has the AC turned on. I have linked the videos of the noise to this post.

The noise does not exist when the car is put on neutral or park. 
This noise is also does not continue as long when the hood is open, but does still occur.

The car drives fine otherwise and there are no jerks or any weird vibrations or anything of that sort.

Here is a link to the videos I recorded [with the hood open](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN3hzYYRb54&feature=youtu.be) and [with the hood closed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYHsr2QSO4U&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  When I put the car in reverse or when the air condition is on maximum, there is a noisy vibration.  I had it checked out by the Honda dealer.  The mechanic drove it around and did not feel or hear the vibration.  The service guy took me and my husband to the back to see if we could identify the noise.  We did and they determined it was the Tensioner.  Honda replace it and there is no more vibration, when the vehicle is in reverse or when the ac is on max.

Answer (score -1):

I’d bet good money it’s the heat shield! Had the same issue. Fkn car was driving me nuts… only in reverse, while a/c was engaged at an idle, while driving over rocky terrain and very seldomly just at idle alone. For me, my heatsheild became warped while caught in a flash flood. Was pretty bad but I was out of it quick and didn’t race thru it or anything. Still made that cringeworthy tra-ra-ra-ra-ra-duh-duh-da sound. All fluids looked good upon inspection n there wasn’t any frothing or loss of power. So I knew it wasn’t the motor or tranny. Jacked it up and saw the plate all crunchy n mangled. Manipulated it back to how I thought it shd look n bolted it up to the frame n BAM! Purrs better than ever. Now in your case it could’ve just vibrated itself loose. Since it’s metal on metal- corrosion is imminent either way. If you know what your doing just drill a hole into the frame making sure to avoid any wiring and just secure it yourself. Otherwise your looking at $300-$1200 repair at a shop. Took me 5 minutes n I didn’t even break a nail LoL. Hope that helps anyone else that finds themselves in this same predicament. I see my answers about 3 years late.